# Proof of Proposition 2.1.1 in Bruns and Herzog

Tags: commutative-algebra, proof-explanation

Let $k$ be a field, $R$ a $k$-algebra and $K$ an extension field of $k$ that is finitely generated over $k$. Then there exists a chain of cyclic extension fields $k=K_0 \subset K_1 \subset \cdots \subset K_t=K$. Fix $i$ and define $T_i = R \otimes_k K_i$ and suppose that $T_i = R[X_1,\dots,X_n]_S/(f_1,\dots,f_m)$ where $X_i$ is indeterminate over $R$, $S$ is a multiplicatively closed set of $R[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ and $f_1,\dots,f_m$ is an $R[X_1,\dots,X_n]_S$-sequence.

> Question: According to the proof of Proposition 2.1.1 in Bruns and Herzog, CMR, $T_i$ is a flat $K_i$-algebra. Why is that true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $k$ is a field, $R$ is flat over $k$. Flatness is stable under (ring) base change, hence $R \otimes_k K_i$ is flat over $K_i$.

Answer (score 2):

Any module over a field is free (vector spaces admit bases) and hence flat.  Since $K_i$ is a field, the $K_i$-algebra $T_i$ is flat.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: Dear Martin, My first thought was to write what you did; then I realized that $K_i$ was itself a field, and so took the cheap route!  Cheers,